# VBA Word: How can I find in which table something (i.e. selection) is?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have in my word document many tables, each is linked to bookmark.
Then I have function which scan document for each tracked change (revisions).
How can I find out where my tracked change is? in which table?

Here is some of my code:

```
Dim ThisWord As Document, TabHead As Table
Set ThisWord = ActiveDocument
Set TabHead = ThisWord.Bookmarks("Head").Range.Tables(1) '"Head" is bookmark for my first table

For Each oRevision In ThisWord.Revisions 'Run through each revision - tracked change
  Select Case oRevision.Type
    Case wdRevisionInsert
        strText = oRevision.Range.Text
        If oRevision.Range.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then 'Check if tracked change is within table
            Select Case oRevision.Range.Table ' <-- How can I change this part???
                    Case TabHead
                         'do some stuff with strText
                   'Case AnotherTable1
                   'Case AnotherTable2
                   '...
            end select
        end if
  end select
next oRevision
```

My main goal is to track down all changes in word document, get date and time and user of that change. By I need to know where that change was made. Tracked change function can give me all that detail, but how to determine where that change was made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the `Range` object, you have acces to all the different objects in the revision. If you want to reference the first `Table` object then use:

```
oRevision.Range.Tables(1)
```

You obviously need to check to see that there *are* tables before using the reference (e.g `If oRevision.Range.Tables.Count > 0 Then ...`).

You could also access the bookmarks collection in the same way:

```
If oRevision.Range.Bookmarks.Count > 0 Then
    Debug.Print oRevision.Range.Bookmarks(1).Name
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the table number of Selection.

```
Sub Demo()
  Dim iTable&
  With Selection
    If Not .Information(wdWithInTable) Then
      MsgBox "The selection is not in a table!"
      Exit Sub
    End If
    For iTable = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
      If (.Range.Start >= ActiveDocument.Tables(iTable).Range.Start) And _
         (.Range.End <= ActiveDocument.Tables(iTable).Range.End) Then
          Exit For
      End If
    Next iTable
  End With
  MsgBox "It's in table # " & iTable
End Sub
```

From macropod https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/microsoft.public.word.programming/%22table%22$20which/microsoft.public.word.programming/Gid7abgeAek/c5rUWhFmWwgJ